# Bootstrap 3 after navbar collapse, toggle wont reopen nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to solve an issue where when I clicked on a navbar menu item in mobile view the navbar remained expanded. this didn't work for me as my menu item was pointing to a div ID. I read here of a solution to add the below to my a href tag.

```
data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"
```

this did not work for me but I could get it to work using a javascript fix I found on github https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12852

```
$(document).on('click','.navbar-collapse.in',function(e) {
if( $(e.target).is('a') ) {
    $(this).collapse('hide');
}
});
```

Now the problem is that after the navbar was hidden I could not open it a second time.

Anyone else have this problem or a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the collapse parameter from `hide` to `toggle`.

```
$(this).collapse('toggle');
```

See more at [bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-usage).