# links to #anchors in navbar not closing after clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I had previously solved issue where my navbar links weren't collapsing after being clicked and thanks to @Kami I had this working using the below code

```
$(document).on('click','.navbar-collapse.in',function(e) {
if( $(e.target).is('a') ) {
$(this).collapse('toggle');
}
});
```

from [Bootstrap 3 after navbar collapse, toggle wont reopen nav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26362404/bootstrap-3-after-navbar-collapse-toggle-wont-reopen-nav)

but when I added this nice function below to keep the navbar from overlapping content it broke.

What part of this function caused the above to break and how can I implement both?

```
  function scrollToAnchor() {
if($(".jquery-anchor").length > 0 && document.URL.indexOf("#") >= 0){
var anchor = document.URL.split("#")[1];
$(".jquery-anchor").each(function() {
    if($(this).attr("name") == anchor) {
        $("html,body").animate({
                scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 50},
            'slow');
        }           
    });

}

}

$(function() {
$("a[href*='#JDG']:not([href='#'])").click(function() {
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
&& location.hostname == this.hostname) {

  var target = $(this.hash);
  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
  if (target.length) {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top - 30 //offsets for fixed header
    }, 1000);
    return false;
  }
 }
 });

 //Executed on page load with URL containing an anchor tag.
 if($(location.href.split("#")[1])) {
  var target = $('#'+location.href.split("#")[1]);
  if (target.length) {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top - 30 //offset height of header here too.
    }, 1000);
    return false;
  }
}


});
```

Using @Shouvik suggestion from [offsetting an html anchor to adjust for fixed header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732690/offsetting-an-html-anchor-to-adjust-for-fixed-header?lq=1)
I changed one line of code to only look for anchors that started with #JDG as without this links to anchors to my modal windows broke.
You can see what is happening [here](http://jdgstrategic.com) where my services menu items wont close after being clicked. the functions are placed at the end of the bootstrap.min.js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jasper pointed out the issue why these weren't working when together.

I just had to remove the

```
return false;
```

from both functions.

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually telling your script to close the menu. In order to do that, add the following line inside your `function scrollToAnchor()` function:

```
$('.navbar-collapse.in').collapse('hide');
```

**EDIT**: Having another look at the script, the above line should be placed inside the following lines instead of `function scrollToAnchor()` function, ie. it has to apply when you click the menu item:

```
$("a[href*='#JDG']:not([href='#'])").click(function() {
    //...
    $('.navbar-collapse.in').collapse('hide');
});
```

Comment: Added that line but no luck. tried in FF and Chrome. also tried changing from 'hide' to 'toggle' as when I used hide originally, any second attempts to open the dropdown didn't work. Did i place it correctly?

Comment: you don't actually have the [**transitions plugin**](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#transitions) included, as instructed by the [**bootstrap documentation on collapse**](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)...

Comment: also, you already have a custom script, why don't you use that instead of adding custom code into standard script?

Comment: from bootstrap "If you're using the compiled (or minified) bootstrap.js, there is no need to include this—it's already there." I'm using the minified version

Comment: you know way more than I do regarding jquery and javascript. The only thing that I know about this is that my custom function that solved my collapse problem broke once I used the animate function. If I take that away it works. My question was can anyone explain why this is? I am trying to use both which I'm sure is possible once I figure out the cause.